# SplitMenuButton in FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'd like to create a SplitMenuButton using FXML. I can find documentation on how to do it in java, but not in the xml file. How can I do this?

Additionally, if there's a good source for FXML documentation, please point me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```xml
<SplitMenuButton fx:id="smButton" text="Text">
    <items>
        <MenuItem text="Choice 1" onAction="#action1" />
        <MenuItem text="Choice 2" onAction="#action2" />
    </items>
</SplitMenuButton>
```

There is an ["Introduction to FXML"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) document that describes how FXML works in general. However, for use cases such as this, you really just need the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitMenuButton.html). Elements beginning with a capital correspond to class names, i.e. they are an instruction to instantiate that class. Attributes correspond to properties, so

```xml
<SplitMenuButton fx:id="smButton" text="Text"/>
```

essentially means

```
SplitMenuButton smButton = new SplitMenuButton();
smButton.setText("Text");
```

The only tricky thing here is the `<items>` element, which is a [Read Only List Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements) as described in the afore-mentioned Introduction to FXML.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. And that's a good tip going forward!